# Create new class object inside WordPress template

Tags: php, wordpress, class

I've a problem. My plan is it to create a new class object inside a WordPress template to pass a variable from the post object to it:

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Ticket
 */

defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

new Test( $post->ID );
```

Inside my class I'm defining an action that adds a AJAX function inside the class:

```
class Test {
    public function __construct( $ticket_id ) {
        $this->ticket_id = $ticket_id;

        $this->register();
    }
    /**
     * Register all hooks
     */
    public function register(): void {
        add_action( 'wp_ajax_test', array( $this, 'test' ) );
    }
    public function test(): void {
        error_log($this->ticket_id);
    }
}
```

The problem is that the AJAX function is not reachable. Maybe it's added too late? Because when I create a new class object directly in my `functions.php` file, it's working. In this case I don't know how to get my post id inside my class.

Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: Where is your "register" called?

Comment: I tried it inside the constructor

Answer (score 1):

First things first:

With separation of concern in mind, you should not use your template to register anything. Your template should be as stupid as possible, as it is only there to render/display things.

Still, you have to call the register function:

```
$testClass = new Test( $post->ID );
$testClass->register();
```

WordPress has a live cycle. I'm not sure if you are able to add a new action there.

Comment: Okay I've tried it like you said but I don't get any AJAX function working.

Comment: Do you understand the concept of ajax? What does your action look like and where do you do the ajax call? (sorry, just try to find the issue it self :) )

Comment: I know that I can send any parameter via AJAX but I'm looking for a better solution. Because when I'm on the page, I already know the post, you know?

Comment: You need to register your action way earlier. And instead of registering it there, you should call it there with the corresponding dependencies. `add_action("wp_ajax_test", [$this, 'test'], 10, 1 );` (the last 1 stand's for amount of arguments). In your template, you call `do_action('wp_ajax_test', $post);`. Now, you should be able to call `error_log($post->ID)`